# Angular js ng-repeat replacing a value with another scope data if they share the same id

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am really new to angular js, so this might be an easy solution for you guys.

I have two data sources, one from db and the second one from third party api. Inside ng-repeat , I am trying to replace one value of the current source with the second source if their id matches. I just want to show in the view and hence i dont need to update db.

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="affiliate in first_source">
                <td>{{affiliate.affiliate_id}}</td>
                <td>${{affiliate.payout | number:2}}</td>#I NEED TO REPLACE THIS VALUE FROM SECOND SOURCE if their id matches.

</tr>


**Origina Source example**
{affiliate_id:1,payout:2,type=test....}

**API SOURCE Example**
{affiliate_id:1,payout:5},{affiliate_id:2,payout:1}

Original outcome
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>test</td>

Required Outcome
<td>1</td>#from original source
<td>5</td>#from second source
<td>test</td>#from original source
```

Any suggestion

Comment: What value are you trying to replace? Would you please show us "expected outcome" and "actual outcome" of what it is you want?

Comment: numerous ways you can do it ... custom filter or a directive or a function in scope

Comment: updated source
@charlietfl if i add a custom filter, how do I use the data (Currently both of them are stored in scope variable)

Comment: one simple way is `{{payout(affiliate)}}` then write a function `$scope.payout=function(affiliate){}` and return what is needed from function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you can do it using filters, directive, controller functions. 
Below is one way to do it. This one does it in the template using ng-if directive.

```
 <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="affiliate in firstSource">
          <td>{{affiliate.id}}</td>
          <td ng-if="affiliate.id==secondSource[$index].id">{{secondSource[$index].payout}}</td>
          <td ng-if="affiliate.id!=secondSource[$index].id">{{affiliate.payout}}</td>
          <td>{{affiliate.type}}</td>
        </tr>
 </tbody>
```

You can preview working version here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/Fze7jcU5Nm3SKlgK4IIU?p=preview

---

If arrays can be in different order, it would be better to call a controller function. Demo as below:
http://plnkr.co/edit/1Jr1B3QL7NPX9nhMfH9x?p=preview

Comment: Your solution handles if both sources are in the same order though

Comment: It depends on what your restrictions are. If your arrays can be in different order, I have updated the post with another plunker that would handle this. However, this one would not work if your array can have duplicate IDs. In that case you have another restriction and you would need more logic to account for that.